# Make CiviMail work with from address a Google Domain!

Tags: civimail

The email for my domain is provided by gmail. However, any time I try to send an email from my CiviServer to that domain only, the email isn't received, and I get:

250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok

> > > RCPT To:
> > >       DATA
> > >       550 5.1.1 ... User unknown
> > >       503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
> > >       RSET
> > >       250 2.0.0 Reset state

I read in this question on Stack Overflow (Sendmail returns error code 550 5.1.1, "User unknown") that the system thinks it needs to send it to itself, so it gets confused (if I've understood correctly).

My question is, what do I do about it? I still want my gmail domain to be my mail handler. But I still need my domain to be able to send emails that will hit my gmail domain inbox.

Should I change my domain name to [REDACTED] and not [REDACTED].com?